# How to search database using jstl tags and display in jsp file

Tags: mysql, jsp, jstl

I am try to search my database using jstl tags but it is not working.
So far what I manage is to make it display a null message.
I am very new to this side of java, so please if you have any suggestion try to explain in details.
Thanks

[Image Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Y0N.png)

My codes are as follows:

user-list.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>    
    <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>

   <html>
  <head>
<title>User Management Application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
         <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname2?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false"
             user="root"  password="root"/>
<body>

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark"
        style="background-color: tomato">
        <div>
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand"> User
                Management App </a>
        </div>

        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/list"
                class="nav-link">Users</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
     </header>
   <br>

<div class="row">
    <!-- <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf='message'>{{message}}</div> -->

    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="text-center">List of Users</h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="container text-left">

            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/new" class="btn btn-success">Add
                New User</a>
        </div>
        

        <form name="userForm" action="user-list.jsp" method="post">
        
              <div class="container text-center">
           
           
              <input type="text" class="form-group" name="search" value="<%=request.getParameter("id")%>" placeholder="Name" style="width: 400px;">
                <INPUT TYPE ="submit">
            
              </div> 
        </form>
        
        <br>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>      
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    
                <sql:query var="user" dataSource="${snapshot}">
                    select *from users where
                    id like '%<%=request.getParameter("id")%>%'
                    
                </sql:query>
                
                
                
                <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUser}">

                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.id}" /></td> 
                        <td><c:out value="${user.name}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.date}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.time}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.email}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.country}" /></td>
                        <td><a href="edit?id=<c:out value='${user.id}' />">Edit</a>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a
                            href="delete?id=<c:out value='${user.id}' />">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                <!-- } -->
            </tbody>
         
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

UserDAO class

```
    package com.project.usermanagement.dao;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.Date;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Time;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.LocalTime;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.project.usermanagement.model.User;


    public class UserDAO {


public static Date getSQLDate(LocalDate date) {
    return java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
}

public static LocalDate getUtilDate(Date sqlDate) {
    return sqlDate.toLocalDate();
}

public static Time getSQLTime(LocalTime time) {
    return java.sql.Time.valueOf(time);
}

public static LocalTime getUtilTime(Time sqlTime) {
    return sqlTime.toLocalTime();
}

private String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname2?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false";
private String jdbcUsername = "root";
private String jdbcPassword = "root";

private static final String INSERT_USERS_SQL = "INSERT INTO users" + "  (name, date ,time ,email , country) VALUES " +
    " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

private static final String SELECT_USER_BY_ID = "select id,name, date, time, email,country from users where id =?";
private static final String SELECT_ALL_USERS = "select * from users";
private static final String DELETE_USERS_SQL = "delete from users where id = ?;";
private static final String UPDATE_USERS_SQL = "update users set name = ?, date=?, time=?, email= ?, country =? where id = ?;";

public UserDAO() {}



protected Connection getConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}

public void insertUser(User user) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println(INSERT_USERS_SQL);
    // try-with-resource statement will auto close the connection.
    try (Connection connection = getConnection(); PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS_SQL)) {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getName());
        preparedStatement.setDate(2, getSQLDate(user.getDate()));
        preparedStatement.setTime(3, getSQLTime(user.getTime()));
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getEmail());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getCountry());
        System.out.println(preparedStatement);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        printSQLException(e);
    }
}

public User selectUser(int id) {
    User user = null;
    // Step 1: Establishing a Connection
    try (Connection connection = getConnection();
        // Step 2:Create a statement using connection object
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_USER_BY_ID);) {
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
        System.out.println(preparedStatement);
        // Step 3: Execute the query or update query
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        // Step 4: Process the ResultSet object.
        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            LocalDate date = rs.getDate("date").toLocalDate();
            LocalTime time = rs.getTime("time").toLocalTime();
            String email = rs.getString("email");
            String country = rs.getString("country");
            user = new User(id, name, date, time , email, country);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        printSQLException(e);
    }
    return user;
}

public List < User > selectAllUsers() {

    // using try-with-resources to avoid closing resources (boiler plate code)
    List < User > users = new ArrayList < > ();
    // Step 1: Establishing a Connection
    try (Connection connection = getConnection();

        // Step 2:Create a statement using connection object
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_ALL_USERS);) {
        System.out.println(preparedStatement);
        // Step 3: Execute the query or update query
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        // Step 4: Process the ResultSet object.
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            LocalDate date = rs.getDate("date").toLocalDate();
            LocalTime time = rs.getTime("time").toLocalTime();
            String email = rs.getString("email");
            String country = rs.getString("country");
            users.add(new User(id, name, date, time, email, country));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        printSQLException(e);
    }
    return users;
}

public boolean deleteUser(int id) throws SQLException {
    boolean rowDeleted;
    try (Connection connection = getConnection(); PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(DELETE_USERS_SQL);) {
        statement.setInt(1, id);
        rowDeleted = statement.executeUpdate() > 0;
    }
    return rowDeleted;
}

public boolean updateUser(User user) throws SQLException {
    boolean rowUpdated;
    try (Connection connection = getConnection(); PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE_USERS_SQL);) {
        statement.setString(1, user.getName());
        statement.setDate(2, getSQLDate(user.getDate()));
        statement.setTime(3, getSQLTime(user.getTime()));
        statement.setString(4, user.getEmail());
        statement.setString(5, user.getCountry());
        statement.setInt(6, user.getId());

        rowUpdated = statement.executeUpdate() > 0;
    }
    return rowUpdated;
}

private void printSQLException(SQLException ex) {
    for (Throwable e: ex) {
        if (e instanceof SQLException) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.err.println("SQLState: " + ((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
            System.err.println("Error Code: " + ((SQLException) e).getErrorCode());
            System.err.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
            Throwable t = ex.getCause();
            while (t != null) {
                System.out.println("Cause: " + t);
                t = t.getCause();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

UserServlet class

```
    package com.project.usermanagement.web;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.LocalTime;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.project.usermanagement.dao.UserDAO;
    import com.project.usermanagement.model.User;


   @WebServlet("/")
   public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private UserDAO userDAO;

public void init() {
    userDAO = new UserDAO();
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    String action = request.getServletPath();

    try {
        switch (action) {
            case "/new":
                showNewForm(request, response);
                break;
            case "/insert":
                insertUser(request, response);
                break;
            case "/delete":
                deleteUser(request, response);
                break;
            case "/edit":
                showEditForm(request, response);
                break;
            case "/update":
                updateUser(request, response);
                break;
            default:
                listUser(request, response);
                break;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new ServletException(ex);
    }
}

private void listUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException {
    List < User > listUser = userDAO.selectAllUsers();
    request.setAttribute("listUser", listUser);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user-list.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

private void showNewForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user-form.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

private void showEditForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws SQLException, ServletException, IOException {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    User existingUser = userDAO.selectUser(id);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user-form.jsp");
    request.setAttribute("user", existingUser);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

}

private void insertUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws SQLException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String country = request.getParameter("country");
    User newUser = new User(name, LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.now(), email, country);
    userDAO.insertUser(newUser);
    response.sendRedirect("list");
}

private void updateUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws SQLException, IOException {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(request.getParameter("date"));
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(request.getParameter("time"));
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String country = request.getParameter("country");

    User book = new User(id, name, date, time, email, country);
    userDAO.updateUser(book);
    response.sendRedirect("list");
}

private void deleteUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws SQLException, IOException {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    userDAO.deleteUser(id);
    response.sendRedirect("list");

}
```

}

Comment: You have apparently already a DAO. You should not use the JSTL SQL taglib then. Moreover, its use is discouraged for non-prototyping.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback. I will try improve the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send value to be search using form .Then , get that value using `${param.yourinputname}` and pass same to your query .Currently , you have *incorrect* input name i.e : `name="search"` but you are getting same using `id` which will return ***null*** as you can see in your added output as well .So, your ***form*** like below :

```
<form name="userForm" action="user-list.jsp" method="post">
     <!--change value--> 
     <input type="text" class="form-group" name="search" value="${param.search}" placeholder="Name" style="width: 400px;">
    <input type ="submit">
</form>
```

Now , when form will get submitted get that the value which is typed by user and pass same to your ***query*** . i.e :

```
<sql:query var="user" dataSource="${snapshot}">
   select *from users where id LIKE '%'  ?   '%'
    <sql:param value="${param.search}" />
</sql:query>
```

And get ***result*** from query using below code :

```
<c:forEach var="listUser" items="${user.rows}"> 
   <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${listUser.id}" /></td> 
    <td><c:out value="${listUser.name}" /></td>
<!--same for other fields as well-->
   </tr>      
</c:forEach>
```